# Can Aerospike be used to store large values?

Tags: memcached, key-value, aerospike

we have a requirement where we would need to store large values (up to 3MB) in a key value store. While we have memcache setup right now, we would want to experiment with aerospike given its performance benchmarks (although with values within a few KBs). I read in the aerospike config about the write-block-size that cannot go beyond 1MB. Does that mean I cannot store value pairs more than 1MB? Or if I can go beyond 1MB, then what should be the acceptable performance benchmarks considering 50/50 read-write).

Answer (score 1):

We see that you posted the same issue on the Aerospike forum, [here](https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/can-aerospike-be-used-to-store-large-values/1974). Below is the answer that @kporter gave; if there are follow-up questions, please continue the discussion on that thread:

"That is correct: presently, records are limited to the **write-block-size**. For larger objects, Aerospike has [Large Lists](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/llist.html), but again, each list element will be limited to the **write-block-size**.

Regarding your question, 'If I can go beyond 1MB, then what should be the acceptable performance benchmarks considering 50/50 read-write', I do not know the precise answer to this question, but the LDT operations are currently significantly slower than normal operations".